# Tkinter button functions

Tags: python, tkinter, button

```
import tkinter

body_label = tk.Label(root, text="Body No.", font=("Arial", 30)) 
body_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=30, pady=60, sticky="ew")
body_entry = tk.Entry(root)
body_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=30, pady=60, sticky="ew")
body_entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", validar_body_no)
botao_limpar_body= tk.Button(root, text="✖", font=("Arial", 12), command=lambda e=body_entry: limpar_campos_body(e))
botao_limpar_body.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=0, pady=10)
```

the code above create one part of my graphic interface. I'm trying to use a IF condition on the button "botao_limpar_body". I want to hide the button if there´s nothing on the "body_entry", if it is, the button will appear again.

Someone can help pls? (Sorry if my english is confuse, I'm brazilian :))

i've try to criate a variable to store the "body_entry" and then start the if condition. To hide the button I tried to use de property "_forget" but didn't work, cause when I initialize the code, my button is hide but when I start to type the button doesn't appear.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing your own class inheriting from `Tk` to avoid using glabal variables. Also are you sure you want to *hide* the button and not just disable it? Hiding can mess with the size of your window.

Disabling:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.body_label = tk.Label(self, text="Body No.", font=("Arial", 30))  
        self.body_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=30, pady=60, sticky="ew")
        self.body_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.body_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=30, pady=60, sticky="ew")  
        self.body_entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.validar_body_no)
        self.botao_limpar_body= tk.Button(self, text="✖", font=("Arial", 12), command=self.some_command, state='disabled')
        self.botao_limpar_body.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=0, pady=10)

    def validar_body_no(self, e):
        if not self.body_entry.get(): 
            self.botao_limpar_body['state']='disabled'
        else:
            self.botao_limpar_body['state']='normal'
        
    def some_command(self):
        pass    # this function does nothing currently


root = MyWindow()
root.mainloop()
```

If you really want to hide the button, you can use `grid_forget`:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.body_label = tk.Label(self, text="Body No.", font=("Arial", 30))  
        self.body_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=30, pady=60, sticky="ew")
        self.body_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.body_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=30, pady=60, sticky="ew")  
        self.body_entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.validar_body_no)
        self.botao_limpar_body= tk.Button(self, text="✖", font=("Arial", 12), command=self.some_command)

    def validar_body_no(self, e):
        if not self.body_entry.get(): 
            self.botao_limpar_body.grid_forget()
        else:
            self.botao_limpar_body.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=0, pady=10)
        
    def some_command(self):
        pass    # this function does nothing currently


root = MyWindow()
root.mainloop()
```